# IIS rewrite rule not passing query parameter

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I think I am trying to do something that should be simple. I want to have a rewrite rule that takes any incoming request, from many domains, and rewrites it to /redirect.aspx?src=original URL

This is what I have

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SimpleURL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.aspx$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/Redirect.aspx?src={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It works except the query parameter being passed is src= without any value.

I made a change so it's now passing a hard coded value for the query parameter

```
I made a change so it is now passing a value for the parameter. 


<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SimpleURL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.aspx$"/>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="src=(.*)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/Redirect.aspx?src=foobar" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If I replace the foobar with {R:0}, no value is passed. enter code hereThe hard coded foobar value is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule looks fine, and works fine on my machine however you are using a permanent redirect. Did you make any changes to the rule while testing? Try testing it from an Incognito/Private mode browser or test a different URL.

Try the following rule:

```
<rule name="SimpleURL" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.aspx$"/>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="src=(.*)" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/Redirect.aspx?src={C:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I made a change so it is now passing a value for the parameter

Comment: I've added a rule to my original answer. Please see if it resolves your issue.